# how to move data from mysql to redis

Tags: mysql, redis

I attempt to put some frequently used data into redis server from mysql . so redis just as a read server ,  i need to move  data from mysql to redis. can anybody recommend a good approache ? i have read some topics and have some thinking share

1、through mysql trigger to record proper data , through timing app move data to redis
2、read mysql logs ,analysis it ,then put it to redis.

BTW: in my application data stored in redis don't need real-time, a little latency is ok.

Comment: Why do you have to move the data? Could you use Redis for caching instead?

Comment: What you said is right .I want aggregate mysql data and put it into redis for frequently read , maybee seperate is more flexible.

Comment: In addition, I don't have plan to persistent redis data, If redis server is down, I can use mysql->redis subsystem restore redis.

Comment: So just use something like https://github.com/sebleier/django-redis-cache as you do with memcached or any other cache.

Comment: @eric Can you share me some experience :)

Comment: I use mysqludf to do above things, add trigger in special table,then mysqludf output data to files,Then i start a timing perl programe to move data into redis. I also found a beta version mysql2redis_udf.so so maybee it's more easier .

Answer (score 2):

I think the mysql udf plugin (https://github.com/Ideonella-sakaiensis/lib_mysqludf_redis) can help you to synchronize data from Mysql to Redis.

example:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TABLE `my_table` (
  id    varchar(16) PRIMARY KEY,
  text  varchar(32)
);
```

set up a trigger for the table and call redis command by mysql udf

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `after_insert_my_table`
AFTER INSERT ON `my_table` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  DO `redis`('redis://@127.0.0.1/0/', 'SET', new.`id`, new.`text`);
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

then you can get value by *my_table* *id*

```
mysql>  SELECT `redis`('redis://@127.0.0.1/0/', 'GET', <my_table id>)\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
`redis`('redis://@127.0.0.1/0/', 'GET', <my_table id>): {
        "out":  <my_table text>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use mass-insert mode of redis-cli.

Check this out - http://dcw.ca/blog/2013/01/02/mysql-to-redis-in-one-step/